# How to calculate how many XTZ will I require to get x amount of tokens from a pool

Tags: dex

I have a Token/XTZ pool in a [Quipuswap v2](https://github.com/madfish-solutions/quipuswap-webapp-2) liquidity pool. I want to calculate how many XTZ will I require to get lets say x amount of tokens from the pool. Can you explain me how is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach is similar to V1.

You need to get reserves and supply using view in the same way as you did before and then use the approach below to calculate the result.

Here is a reference implementation in TS for calculating how many token A you have to provide to buy `bTokenAmount` of token b:

```
export const findAmmSwapInput = (
  bTokenAmount: BigNumber,
  pair: RoutePairWithDirection
) => {
  const feeRatio = getPairFeeRatio(pair);
  const numerator = pair.aTokenPool.times(bTokenAmount);
  const denominator = pair.bTokenPool.minus(bTokenAmount).times(feeRatio);
  const input = numerator.idiv(denominator).plus(1);
  return input.isGreaterThan(0) ? input : new BigNumber(Infinity);
};
```

Notes:
`idiv` - division where only integer part is left (ex. 3.idiv(2) = 1)
`feeRatio`  - 0.9965

Comment: Got it ... Thanks.
BTW
The fee ratio will be constant right? because I will be implementing this in smartpy so, if its variable then I will need to handle it.

Comment: It can be changed but we don't have a view for them. 

You can find the fees in the storage (interface_fee + auction_fee +swap_fee). Don't add withdrawal_fee - it's for other mechanics

Comment: Okk ... I can create an entrypoint for that to update by admin then. BTW what scaling factor are you using in contracts to handle decimal numbers?

Comment: 1e18 on V2, if I am not mistaken. Check. If division of fees sum by 1e18 gives 0.0035, it's 1e18